# pgf: copy codeexample style

Tags: tikz-pgf, documentation

I'm using pgfmanual to document a library and the nice looking `codeexample` environment to typeset a codeblock + the resulting image. However, I'd like to use a the same style (lstlisting is too different) to typeset a code, without the result (the reasonis that the code calls verbatim code from xsim, and cannot be included in codeexample that does not accept verbatim environments).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file `pgfmanual-en-macros.tex` defines an option `code only` for `codeexample`. Therefore, I assume that

```
\begin{codeexample}[code only]
```

suppresses the typeset result.

Comment: Good catch, thanks a lot! By any chance, do you know if it is possible 1) to do a `result only`, i.e. print only the result typeset in this yellow box 2) to do a `codeexample` that works for verbatim content?

Comment: So for 1) I found `\colorbox{graphicbackground}{\input{\robExtPathToInput}}`, where you can wrap the input inside a minipage of the wanted width like in the code https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/master/tex/latex/pgf/doc/pgfmanual-en-macros.tex for 2) if you can write the file to an external file, it is just `\codeexample[vbox, from file={\robExtPathToInput}]`, otherwise I found a solution that I will explain in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/695208/pgf-codeexample-with-verbatim-code-with-mwe-now