# pgf: codeexample with verbatim code

Tags: tikz-pgf, verbatim, documentation

I'm using pgfmanual to document a library and the nice looking `codeexample` environment to typeset a code block + the result. However, I'd like to use it when the code contains verbatim code.

Is it possible?

MWE (note that I use `+v` for simplicity, in practice I mostly use the `xsim` package to read the arguments and write them to a file... but hopefully it is not too different) fails with:

```
ERROR: LaTeX cmd Error: Verbatim-like command '\testVerbatim' illegal in argument.
```

```
\documentclass[a4paper,doc2]{ltxdoc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,fit}
% Loads the great package that produces tikz-like manual (see also tikzcd for examples)
\input{pgfmanual-en-macros.tex} % Is supposed to be included in recent TeX distributions, but I get errors...
\usepackage{verbatim}

\NewDocumentCommand{\testVerbatim}{+v}{
\begin{flushleft}\ttfamily%
#1
\end{flushleft}}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\begin{document}

\begin{codeexample}[vbox]
  This works fine: $\delta$.
\end{codeexample}

\testVerbatim{I can put # or even % in this sentence}

\begin{codeexample}[vbox]
  \testVerbatim{I can put # or even % in this sentence}
\end{codeexample}
  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please give us a MWE to start from.

Comment: @Teepeemm done (sorry I was on my phone, so hard to test)

Comment: The `xparse` documentation says: “A command with a verbatim argument will produce an error when it appears within an argument of another function.” There's even more to the error: “The command '\testVerbatim' takes a verbatim argument and should therefore normally not be used in arguments of other commands or environments. LaTeX found an illegal token (\code@post ) after '{I can put # or even \ignorespaces^^M' and will drop everything up to this point.” (`\code@post` is part of the `codeexample` setup.)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel well, you can use `\testVerbatim` inside a tcolorbox for instance. Actually I don't think there is any fundamental reason why such thing is impossible (and I am actually implementing this workaround right now that seems to work for now, by reading the content of the environment using xsim, writting it in a file, and then I can do basically anything I want from here, like including that file, inputing that file etc…)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel So I managed do to what I wanted, except that the style is ugly because I do `\verbatiminput{\myfile}`. Any idea if `codeexample` can accept the path to a file?

Comment: @tobiasBora I don't have much knowledge about verbatim and especially how `codeexample` is set up. It's 350 lines long. However, it does have a [`from file` key](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/6833aa6de480eae1c7b7aeaa936bf31204c95579/tex/latex/pgf/doc/pgfmanual-en-macros.tex#L1615) which seems promising.

Comment: Yeah, I was not sure how to use it but I finally found that one must use it like `\codeexample[code only, from file={\robExtPathToInput}]`. I finally have what I want, it is not trivial, but works ^^'

Comment: Ok, I simplified the code, see my answer.

Comment: Don't be lemmings and vote just because others have voted. The Q was edited in a reasonable amount of time and at that point didn't qualify for the close reason, imo. If it still does, please comment why you need more details? Looks like OP provided enough details for me and them to figure out a solution with a bit back-and-forth. Maybe there's even a better solution?

Answer (score 3):

I finally found a solution (edit: see below for a more robust one), using `xsim` to write the content to a file, and then I used the `from file` key:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,doc2]{ltxdoc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,fit}
% Loads the great package that produces tikz-like manual (see also tikzcd for examples)
\input{pgfmanual-en-macros.tex} % Is supposed to be included in recent TeX distributions, but I get errors...
\usepackage{verbatim}
\RequirePackage{xsimverb} % To easily write verbatim code to files
\NewDocumentEnvironment{codeAndResult}{}{\XSIMfilewritestart{\jobname-robExt-tmp-file-you-can-remove.tmp}}%
{%
  \XSIMfilewritestop%
  \codeexample[leave comments, vbox, from file={\jobname-robExt-tmp-file-you-can-remove.tmp}]%
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\testVerbatim}{+v}{
\begin{flushleft}\ttfamily%
#1
\end{flushleft}}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\begin{document}

\begin{codeexample}[vbox]
  This works fine: $\delta$.
\end{codeexample}

\testVerbatim{I can put # or even % in this sentence}

\begin{codeAndResult}
  \testVerbatim{I can put # or even % in this sentence}
\end{codeAndResult}
  
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

I find this version more reliable as sometimes the previous solution was not printing anything:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,doc2]{ltxdoc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,fit}
% Loads the great package that produces tikz-like manual (see also tikzcd for examples)
\input{pgfmanual-en-macros.tex} % Is supposed to be included in recent TeX distributions, but I get errors...
\usepackage{verbatim}
\RequirePackage{xsimverb} % To easily write verbatim code to files
\NewDocumentEnvironment{codeAndResult}{}{\XSIMfilewritestart{\jobname-codeAndResult-tmp-file-you-can-remove.tmp}}%
{%
  \XSIMfilewritestop%
  \par
  \medskip
  \noindent\colorbox{graphicbackground}{\noindent\begin{minipage}{1.0\linewidth}
  {\input{\jobname-codeAndResult-tmp-file-you-can-remove.tmp}}
  \end{minipage}}
  % I don't know why, but sometimes this prints nothing, while input works:
  %{\codeexample[width=0pt, leave comments, vbox, from file={\jobname-codeAndResult-tmp-file-you-can-remove.tmp}]}%
  {\codeexample[code only, from file={\jobname-codeAndResult-tmp-file-you-can-remove.tmp}]}%
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\testVerbatim}{+v}{
\begin{flushleft}\ttfamily%
#1
\end{flushleft}}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\begin{document}

\begin{codeexample}[vbox]
  This works fine: $\delta$.
\end{codeexample}

\testVerbatim{I can put # or even % in this sentence}

\begin{codeAndResult}
  \testVerbatim{I can put # or even % in this sentence}
\end{codeAndResult}
  
\end{document}
```